# MySQL Order by NULL join

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to do an ORDER BY where I want any rows without an entry in the join table to appear at the bottom of the list and then organised by name. Simplified tables are:

users (id, name)
photos (id, filename, user_id)

So far I have:

```
SELECT name FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON photos.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY *ANSWER HERE*, name DESC
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(photos.id), name DESC
```

The [ISNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) function will return 1 or 0, which will conveniently sort in the right order for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON photos.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY photos.user_id DESC, name DESC
```

`ORDER BY photos.user_id DESC` will show NULL values at the end.

Comment: is my answer completely off track? O_o